# Save form inputs to txt, popup result, no page changing

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, response

I would like to build a newsletter subscription function to my website. and I want to get all the input save into a txt file in the host folder. However, I don't want to switch page after people submit it. Just show a popup message saying "Thank You for Subscribing" will be perfect. I know how to do it with PHP to show a message in a separate page, but not sure how to do it in a popup box. Here is my html and PHP code. Please help, thanks a lot.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="post">
        <input name="field1" type="text" />
        <input name="field2" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
    </form>
    <a href='data.txt'>Text file</a>
</body>
```

PHP function is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: Use AJAX in HTML file. For requests

Comment: i really suggest a database over a flat file, you will be very grateful as it grows.

Comment: Html form is intended to work like that, to change location on submit, but the best part is you can prevent it using JS but you have to use ajax to send the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have included jQuery to your page, something like following should work:

```
// process the form
$('form').submit(function(event) {

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'field1'              : $('input[name=field1]').val(),
        'field2'             : $('input[name=field2]').val()
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'myprocessingscript.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    encode          : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data); 
            // data is the output from your php, check it and display alert appropriately

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();



});
```

Take a look at [source article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery)